# Why is my managed instance database encryption is not being disabled?

Tags: encryption, transactions, azure-sql-database, replication, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to disable encryption on a database which is hosted inside Azure managed instance. I am not able to disable the encryption for it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have tried this alter database query:

```
ALTER DATABASE "DATABASE-NAME" SET ENCRYPTION OFF
```

I had checked encryption on each database as:

```
SELECT name, is encrypted
FROM sys.databases;
ALTER DATABASE "DATABASE-NAME" SET ENCRYPTION OFF
```

The query I used to alter the database turns out run successfully but the encryption is not disabled.

Comment: Please format your codes properly

Comment: likely it just takes time to complete this in the background as you have to rewrite each page in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It may take some time to complete. On databases of less than 100 GB you may find it takes 20-25 minutes to complete.

You can monitor de progress using below query:

```
SELECT DB.NAME, DEK.ENCRYPTION_STATE, DEK.PERCENT_COMPLETE
FROM SYS.DM_DATABASE_ENCRYPTION_KEYS AS DEK
FULL JOIN SYS.DATABASES AS DB
   ON DB.DATABASE_ID = DEK.DATABASE_ID
ORDER BY DB.NAME
```